# Autofac Exception Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException when resolving dependencies

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, autofac

I am fairyly new to Xamarin.Forms
In the Shared Project I have a **Resolver class**:

```
public static class Resolver
{
    private static IContainer container;

    public static void Initialize(IContainer container)
    {
        Resolver.container = container;
    }

    public static T Resolve<T>()
    {
        return container.Resolve<T>();
    }
}
```

and the **Bootstrap class**:

```
public static class Bootstrapper
{
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<MainShell>();
        containerBuilder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(App).Assembly).Where(x => x.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ViewModel)));
        var container = containerBuilder.Build();
        Resolver.Initialize(container);
    }
}
```

The App.xaml.cs only calls and resolves the **MainShell class**

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Bootstrapper.Initialize();
        MainPage = Resolver.Resolve<MainShell>();
    }
}
```

The exception is always getting thrown in the resolver class at the Resolve methode.
The complete exception is as following:
**Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: 'An exception was thrown while activating News2.MainShell.**'

Comment: Hi, `MainPage` is a type of `Page` . Need to check whether `Resolver.Resolve<MainShell>()` will return a `Page` object.

Comment: Probably a good idea to post the whole exception. The exception usually has a hint as to _why_ it was thrown, like maybe it couldn't resolve a dependency or that there was a problem running the class constructor.

Comment: This is the whole exception in VisualStudio "{Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while activating News2.MainShell. ---> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor()' on type 'MainShell'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: ShellContent Content should be of type Page.

The Resolver.Resolve returns a T object as shown in the code snippet above.